# serialize runtime objects into svcutil generated partial class representations

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization, wolfram-mathematica, svcutil.exe

I use svcutil to generate the following code:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.239
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace System.Net
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;


    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="EndPoint", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Net")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(System.Net.IPEndPoint))]
    public partial class EndPoint : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    {

        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="IPEndPoint", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Net")]
    public partial class IPEndPoint : System.Net.EndPoint
    {

        private System.Net.IPAddress m_AddressField;

        private int m_PortField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
        public System.Net.IPAddress m_Address
        {
            get
            {
                return this.m_AddressField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.m_AddressField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
        public int m_Port
        {
            get
            {
                return this.m_PortField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.m_PortField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="IPAddress", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Net")]
    public partial class IPAddress : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    {

        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        private long m_AddressField;

        private System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily m_FamilyField;

        private int m_HashCodeField;

        private ushort[] m_NumbersField;

        private long m_ScopeIdField;

        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
        public long m_Address
        {
            get
            {
                return this.m_AddressField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.m_AddressField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
        public System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily m_Family
        {
            get
            {
                return this.m_FamilyField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.m_FamilyField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
        public int m_HashCode
        {
            get
            {
                return this.m_HashCodeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.m_HashCodeField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
        public ushort[] m_Numbers
        {
            get
            {
                return this.m_NumbersField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.m_NumbersField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true)]
        public long m_ScopeId
        {
            get
            {
                return this.m_ScopeIdField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.m_ScopeIdField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
namespace System.Net.Sockets
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;


    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="AddressFamily", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Net.Sockets")]
    public enum AddressFamily : int
    {

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Unknown = -1,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Unspecified = 0,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Unix = 1,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        InterNetwork = 2,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        ImpLink = 3,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Pup = 4,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Chaos = 5,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        NS = 6,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Ipx = 6,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Iso = 7,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Osi = 7,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Ecma = 8,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        DataKit = 9,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Ccitt = 10,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Sna = 11,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        DecNet = 12,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        DataLink = 13,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Lat = 14,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        HyperChannel = 15,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        AppleTalk = 16,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        NetBios = 17,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        VoiceView = 18,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        FireFox = 19,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Banyan = 21,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Atm = 22,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        InterNetworkV6 = 23,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Cluster = 24,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Ieee12844 = 25,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Irda = 26,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        NetworkDesigners = 28,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Max = 29,
    }
}


[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="IConnectionHost", CallbackContract=typeof(IConnectionHostCallback), SessionMode=System.ServiceModel.SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IConnectionHost
{

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IConnectionHost/OpenTunnel", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IConnectionHost/OpenTunnelResponse")]
    bool OpenTunnel(int serverPort);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IConnectionHost/CloseTunnel", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IConnectionHost/CloseTunnelResponse")]
    bool CloseTunnel(int serverPort);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IConnectionHost/DisconnectAtHost", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IConnectionHost/DisconnectAtHostResponse")]
    bool DisconnectAtHost(int serverPort, System.Net.IPEndPoint client);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IConnectionHost/Reply", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IConnectionHost/ReplyResponse")]
    int Reply(int serverPort, System.Net.IPEndPoint client, [System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name="reply")] byte[] reply1);
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface IConnectionHostCallback
{

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay=true, Action="http://tempuri.org/IConnectionHost/Relay")]
    void Relay(int serverPort, System.Net.IPEndPoint client, byte[] message);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay=true, Action="http://tempuri.org/IConnectionHost/DisconnectAtClient")]
    void DisconnectAtClient(int serverPort, System.Net.IPEndPoint client);
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface IConnectionHostChannel : IConnectionHost, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
{
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class ConnectionHostClient : System.ServiceModel.DuplexClientBase<IConnectionHost>, IConnectionHost
{

    public ConnectionHostClient(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext callbackInstance) : 
            base(callbackInstance)
    {
    }

    public ConnectionHostClient(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext callbackInstance, string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(callbackInstance, endpointConfigurationName)
    {
    }

    public ConnectionHostClient(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext callbackInstance, string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(callbackInstance, endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public ConnectionHostClient(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext callbackInstance, string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(callbackInstance, endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public ConnectionHostClient(System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext callbackInstance, System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(callbackInstance, binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public bool OpenTunnel(int serverPort)
    {
        return base.Channel.OpenTunnel(serverPort);
    }

    public bool CloseTunnel(int serverPort)
    {
        return base.Channel.CloseTunnel(serverPort);
    }

    public bool DisconnectAtHost(int serverPort, System.Net.IPEndPoint client)
    {
        return base.Channel.DisconnectAtHost(serverPort, client);
    }

    public int Reply(int serverPort, System.Net.IPEndPoint client, byte[] reply1)
    {
        return base.Channel.Reply(serverPort, client, reply1);
    }
}
```

Then in Mathematica (8) & .NET/Link create an IPEndPoint object:

```
ep // ClearAll
ep[port_] := NETNew["System.Net.IPEndPoint", NETNew["System.Net.IPAddress", {127, 0, 0, 1}], port_]

retargetedEndPoint=ep@900
```

and try to call:

```
.Reply(.,retargetedEndPoint,.)
```

The problem is the Mathematica IPEndPoint object is of the genuine System.NET.IPEndPoint type whereas the expected one is some serialized representation!

1. How can I convert the latter?
2. How do these partial classes svcutil generates behave, do they extend?? the definitions of the real System.NET.IPEndPoint types or merely shadow them as it is assumed C# compilers (not the runtime) will automatically handle the necessary conversions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look right that you would generate anything in the System.Net namespace.  I think maybe you want to use the `/reference:<file path>` option of svcutil so that it know where to look for existing types.

Comment: This does the trick! I am working on a Mathematica package that generates event dispatcher types that implement WCF duplex service callback interfaces: callback methods propagate to Mathematica via events. I had automated everything but kind of stalled at this step, was pretty bored doing all the wiring necessary to make it work. Now I will just reference a good chunk of .NET assemblies by default and give my users options to override this behavior if need be.

Comment: Wow just retested retargeting! Everything works like a charm with properly referenced types: http://portfusion.sourceforge.net/i/mathematica-wcfservices-duplex.png

Comment: Awesome. I always like seeing my name in lights!  :)